# Internal Link 'Target' dropdown options not populating

Tags: content-editor, links, fieldtype

We are using sc8.0u5. When the *Insert Link* of a *General Link* field is clicked, there is a Select Target dropdown. But there are no options being populated in it.

This works fine in the DEV system but not in the UAT environment. Both have the same sc versions. However, UAT is a multi-site instance.

I tried the fix [here](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/general-link-field-bug-with-internal-links-opening-in-new-window/) but no luck.

Comment: What value do you have set in the Root field of this item `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/TargetsSearchPanelConfig` ? (This is in the Core DB)

Comment: @RichardSeal It is `/sitecore/client/business component library/system/texts/targets`

Answer (score 0):

Add the Versions for the below childs of Targets
/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/Targets

Then check the Internal Link, you will see 2 entries in Target dropdown.

After that remove the latest version and again check the Internal Link. You can see those Targets dropdown values